# How to connect a pneumatic cylinder to a door?

Tags: pneumatic

I have this pneumatic cylinder that I wish to connect to a wooden door in order to make it kinda like a Star wars door.  I'm wondering what the best way to connect the cylinder to the door would be.

The cylinder has a threaded rod at the end. Looks like the one attached.  I was wondering if there are components like a bracket that can be screwed onto the door and has a threaded loop to which the Rod could be screwed to?[image][image]

Comment: I suggest to greatly fix your first image...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the threads at the end of your sample cylinder, you would be seeking a female threaded rod end:

[image: female threaded rod end]

There are a multitude of variations of this product, almost always including the words "rod end" with different modifiers. You could have a forked threaded rod end.

[image: forked threaded rod end]

It would not have to be female threads, of course. Depending on the work load, you may not have to have the bearing insert of the first image, although it allows for longer life and easier alignment in use.